# What is the proper algorithm for using Table<TEntity> and LINQ to filter a search?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I'll explain my setup. I have a table like

```
    fileid    |                 orgid                      |              catid              |       fname
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1        |                   2                        |               1                 |      "mypowerpoint.ppt"
     2        |                   7                        |               12                |      "someworddoc.docx"
     3        |                   4                        |               8                 |      "homepageimg.jpg"
     4        |                   9                        |               4                 |      "some_text_document.txt"
```

and two associated tables like

```
    catid   |        orgid               |  catname   
 -------------------------------------------------
     1      |        1                   |  "Some Category"
     2      |        1                   |  "Some other Category"
     3      |        2                   |  "Category XYZ"
     4      |        3                   |  "My category"
```

and

```
    orgid   |     orgname   
 ---------------------------------- 
     1      |     Company A
     2      |     Company B
     3      |     Company C
     4      |     Company D
```

With these in the background, a user is supposed to filter down their search for a file name (`fname`) if they so choose. The search checks whether the search they put is contained in any file name. They can filter their search by Organization and/or Category. Those filters each come in the form of a dropdown list and they select "All" if they're not using the filter. Their search results are returned as rows of an HTML table.

Here's my method that returns those search results:

```
    public ActionResult Search (string selectedOrgName, string selectedCatName, string searchVal)
    {
        PortalData PD = new PortalData();

        string htmlRows = "";

        foreach (AssetFile f in PD.files)
        {
            if (f.filename.Contains(searchVal))
            {
                string fOrgName = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgid == f.orgid).orgname;
                string fCatName = PD.cats.FirstOrDefault(c => c.catid == f.catid).catname;
                if (    (selectedOrgName == "ALL" || fOrgName == selectedOrgName)
                     && (selectedCatName == "ALL" || fCatName == selectedCatName) )
                {
                    htmlRows += "<tr>" + "<td><input type=\"checkbox\"/></td><td>" + fOrgName + "</td><td>" + fCatName + "</td><td>" + f.filename + "</td></tr>";  
                }

            }
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlRows)) htmlRows = "No results found!"; 

        return Content(htmlRows, "text/html");
    }
```

The problem is that it seems very ugly and possibly inefficient and definitely not scalable if I'm going to add new filters in the future. I'm wondering what the correct way is of doing this.

Comment: the uglier part here is that you are building out the html result in a string and returning that - this is also the part that is not scalable.  Fix that and use the tools that MVC framework comes with to pass data to the view and render the data in the view .... then worry about the querying of the data

Comment: I'm new to MVC. Could tell me which tool, specifically, I should be looking for?

Comment: create a new class with just the properities that will be seen in the html , then bind the view to this new object.  Then in the view you do a foreach loop over the Model and display a row for each item

Answer (score 0):

I would address my comment first , but as for the query , try something like:

```
IQueryable<myTable> PortalData;

// here is your first search / filter
PortalData = PortalData.Where(x => x.filename.contains(q));

// here is later future filters
// just an example of another filter on top of first one
PortalData = PortalData.Where(x => x.Id < whatever)

return PortalData.Select(x =>  new { x.orgName , x.catName });
```